# How to register a custom control on ATL/WTL dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, atl, wtl

I've derived a custom control from `ATL::CWindowImpl<CMyCustomControl>` and declared `DECLARE_WND_CLASS(_T("CMyCustomControl"))`.

I've also made a dialog resource with a custom control with the class name `CMyCustomControl`.

How do I go about registering the control properly so I can display it on the dialog?

Comment: You might find what you're looking for in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575532/pre-registering-an-atl-window-class Evidently it's not possible.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Shooooot... is this really "pre-registering" though? I really don't care *when* it's registered (nothing 3rd-party-y going on), I just want it to show up... sounds like something pretty standard for a custom control...

Comment: If you want the resource to automatically create the control when the dialog is created, then obviously Windows has to know about the window class beforehand. The tactic of creating a dummy control and subclassing in OnInitDialog works quite well though.

Answer (score 2):

There are thre typical way to create custom controls in WTL.

1. `DECLARE_WND_CLASS`/`DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS` + `RegisterClassEx` API to register class by name + custom control reference in dialog template to instantiate control through class name
2. Implement window class, esp. inheriting from `CWindowImpl`, and create control manually, esp. from `OnCreate`/`OnInitDialog`
3. Implement window class, instantiate standard control through dialog template, and subclass the control instance to alter its behavior (e.g. static with hyperlinks, custom list view, edit control with color highlighting etc)

With all three you need to do more than just a macro in class definition. You will find great examples here: http://www.viksoe.dk/code/all_wtl.htm under "Controls" section.

Certainly the fourth method is implementing an ActiveX control.

Comment: Forgot about viksoe.dk.  +1 -- thanks for the reference.